# Resize hard drive partition without losing data

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, backup, windows-7

I am stuck on Ubuntu with little knowledge. I want to go back to windows 7 but my hard drive has just one partition with all my data and Ubuntu on it. I have a bootable windows 7 stick. How do I get back to windows 7 without losing my data? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Backup your data, boot & install windows, then restore your data from backups. You've provided no specifics that are helpful, and we don't support windows. We don't know what Ubuntu product you are/were using, what release of that product, what file-system you had on it, but most file-systems used by Ubuntu are **not** usable by windows, thus backup & restoring data from backups is usually easiest

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

All data will be erased during the install process of the new Operating System (OS). Formatting the partition is a mandatory step of migrating from Ubuntu to Windows.

Any data that you wish to retain must be moved to some other media before beginning to install the new OS.